# Rails How to Implement a Search for Multiple Values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to implement a "checkbox search" that will allow a user to filter out records based on what parameters they select (such as "Full time", "Part time", "Contractor" job_type). My current code only allows the user to search one job_type, not one and/or another.

My current set up looks like this:

Index Controller Action:

```
def index
  @jobs = Job.search(params[:search])
end
```

Index View:

```
<%= form_tag jobs_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <p>
    <%= check_box_tag :search, value = "Contractor", params[:search] %>
    <%= check_box_tag :search, value = "Part time", params[:search] %>
   <%= check_box_tag :search, value = "Full time", params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :job_type => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Job Model:

```
  def self.search(search)
    if search
      find(:all, :conditions => ['job_type LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
    else
      find(:all)
    end
  end
```

How can this code be modified to allow someone to search for "Part time" and/or "Full time", etc. job records?

Comment: Looking at your code, I noticed that job_type is a field which can have the the value 'Contractor', 'Part Time', 'Full Time', then why have you used `job_type LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"` instead of job_type = ?', "%#{search}%" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to change your view code to something like below so that multiple values of search parameters can be sent from the form

View Code

```
<%= form_tag jobs_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <%= check_box_tag "search[]", "Contractor" %>
  <%= label_tag "Contractor" %>
  <%= check_box_tag "search[]", "Part Time" %>
  <%= label_tag "Part Time" %>
  <%= check_box_tag "search[]", "Full Time", %>
  <%= label_tag "Full Time" %>
<% end %>
```

Then in Model you need to change the search query to search based on multiple parameters like this

```
def self.search(search)
  if search.blank?
    all
  else
    where("job_type IN (?)", search)
  end
end
```

search parameter will be an array with selected values from the view

Model query is rails 3 compatible